# How can I modify the output pattern of Laravel return object?

Tags: c#, .net, json, laravel

The image is the output of a code like : `return $data;` where `$data= MyModel::where("...")->get();`

[image]

I want not no get :

1. The trailing 3rd bracket.
2. The " (double quotation), rather I want to get ' (single quotation), because in C# desktop app I can't parse a double quoted string, is there a way ?
3. Any \ (back slash character). Actually in output every / (forward slash) is concatenate with a with a \ (back slash).
   The red marked string in actual output is like : "/1st Year/1st Semester/Assignment paper ), although \ isn't interpreted in output image

What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you can hide attributes by defining `$hidden` in your models, So if you models is named `MyModel` you can have something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'full_dir_url'
    ];

}
```

Hope this helps.